# Ubuntu Desktop app, allow for navigation through files with arrow keys

Tags: gnome, launcher

I cannot find the correct terminology to phrase the question, so please edit.

In the Eye of Gnome, and most image viewer apps, if I have a directory of images (image_1.png,...image_n.png), then when I click on an image in that directory, I will see the image preview. Then while the image is open, if I click the left/right arrows on the keyboard, it will replace the contents of the viewer with the previous/next image in that directory. I do not understand how the Eye of Gnome (or the other image viewers) get the next filename when I click the left/right arrow. What is the mechanism to get the next filename?

I am asking because I need a "viewer" for a different filetype, and would like the same functionality.

I already created the Desktop file and put it in /usr/share/applications. This means that when I double click on this custom filetype, it correctly opens in the program that I generated. But I do not understand how to enable handling of the left/right arrows either in the .desktop file or in the C++ application iteself. For reference, here is the .desktop file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=gnome-panel-launcher
Name[en_US]=Custom Viewer
Exec=/home/bob/Desktop/custom_viewer/bin/custom_viewer %F
Name=Custom Viewer
Icon=gnome-panel-launcher
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, that functionality to browse through different files is not provided by the operating system, but by the application `eog` itself.

In your C++ application, you will need to implement this yourself. You will need to write code that makes your program to read the contents of the folder where the opened file resides. Then, you need to implement the keybindings that causes your application to load the next or previous file in the list.